# How to write a regexp pattern that is not nested inside another pattern

Tags: php, regex, pcre

Suppose the text is as follows:

```
some text \( {{my}} \) more text \(some\) text {{my}} more text
some text {{my}} more text some text {{my}} more text
```

The text contains two special patterns: `{{...}}` and `\(...\)`, and the `{{...}}` pattern can be nested in `\(...\)` pattern in the text.

My task is to write a regexp (in php, so PCRE engine) that will match all `{{..}}` patterns which are not nested inside a `\(...\)` pattern. So for the example text above, the regexp should return only 3 `{{...}}` patterns, because the first is nested in `\(...\)`.

Well, the pattern to find all `{{...}}` is `/\{\{(?P<options>.*?)\}\}/g` and I have a regex101 fiddle for it here: http://regex101.com/r/cQ1tQ4/1

Is it possible to create a pattern as I described above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest approach is to match `outer whatever outer | (inner)` and take the captured group:

```
\\(.+?\\)|{{(.+?)}}
```

http://regex101.com/r/fX6sX8/3

Answer (score 0):

You could do this through PCRE verbs `(*SKIP)(*F)`,

```
\\\([^{}]*\{\{[^}]*\}\}[^\\]*\\\)(*SKIP)(*F)|\{\{(?P<options>[^}]*)\}\}
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/cQ1tQ4/2)